# Easiest way to change dropout rate of existing model in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It appears that

```
model.layers[n].rate
```

can be viewed and changed, but does not reach the back end and actually change training behavior. What's the easiest way to change it for real?  I'm hoping not to have to make a whole new model and transfer the weights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be:

1. Change the rates in the layers
   `model.layers[i].rate = 0.04  #layer[i] is the dropout layer`
2. Clone this model to a new model using
   `model = keras.models.clone(model) #weights would be reinitialized`
3. Compile the new model
   `model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=...) #optimizer state would be reset`
4. Set the original weights to the new clone model
   `model.load_weights(file_weights) #load weights`

Discussion on this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8826).

Comment: Thanks.  I did come across this, but it's only slightly easier than starting fresh.  I also am currently stuck regarding cloning my model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753753/in-keras-how-can-you-clone-a-model-with-custom-objects

Comment: I already requested more info on your other question. @Mastiff